# Android App to WAMP Server Connection

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, wamp

I have a html form that is submitting data. The data is given to a php file through jquery post. The php changes values to a mysql database on the wamp server. I have put the app on android through phonegap. When I download the app to the device (through eclipse) and try to submit the form nothing happens. However if I run the same code on the android browser the code works.

How do I make the code work on the app like it does on the browser?

Comment: Does your app have internet permissions?

Comment: The computer that I am using to code is different from this computer (that one does not have internet). There is supposed to be no data in or out from that computer so I am out of luck in terms of putting code here other that manually retyping the code....

Comment: How do check for internet permissions?

Comment: My xml file already has <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Answer (score 0):

a few things.

1: make sure your app has internet permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

2: make sure your webview has javascript enabled

```
WebView m_webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webMain);
WebSettings webSettings = m_webview.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

javascript is disabled by default for security reasons. as your posting with jquery, this seems like the most likely possibility.